# Conditional mean calculation in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a dataset organized as following :

[image: My dataset]

The column A is the name

The column B is the date

The column C is the value registered for that person in that day

How can i calculate for the whole dataset a mean of the value of that person in the 30 past days without manually ordering for name and making the mean checking the date?

Comment: You could add some additional columns to COUNTIF(col = "Jack"), get a SUMIF (col where col = "Jack") and write your MEAN against those two.

Comment: but how can i count only the "Jack" in the past 30 days? I can sum the value for the days but for the names?

Comment: Have you tried the [AVERAGEIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-48910C45-1FC0-4389-A028-F7C5C3001690)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [AVERAGEIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-48910C45-1FC0-4389-A028-F7C5C3001690) with the [EDATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edate-function-1586b161-4361-4a6d-939b-9d96eae962a8) giving you a one month window.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(C:C, A:A, "Jack", B:B, ">"&EDATE(TODAY(), -1), B:B, "<="&TODAY())
```

[image: averageifs_dated]

Comment: Damn you are quick! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter instead of Enter):

=AVERAGE(IF($A$2:$A$15=A2,IF($B$2:$B$15>=TODAY()-30,$C$2:$C$15,""),""))

Comment: While this could work, using 'natural' array functions (like AVERAGEIFS) instead of 'forced' array functions gives increased performance, is more readable, and is more foolproof (can't enter the cell and accidentally exit without CSE). Good principle for cases where a 'forced' array formula is required, however.

Comment: I concur, forced array formulae are a bit of a double-edged sword (by the way, I like the term 'forced' array formula, first time I come across it in all those years...)

Answer (score 0):

Add columns for these two fomulas:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A4,"Jack")
=SUMIF(A1:A4,"Jack",C10:C13)
```

That will give you the count, and it will give you the sum.  With those two you can calculate the mean.
That's the basic idea, anyway.
Of course, you can add another count for the date ranges.  It's all the same sort of thing.

Comment: if i write this in my first cell and then try to drag the function to the bottom of the datasets i think the mean would be wrong because the countif would show the total values of jack and the summit the sum of the values in the past 30 days where there is jack, which is different from the total values of jack from the dataset.

Comment: That's why I suggested doing an additional row for the date ranges.